# Call a boot event laravel

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, model, boot

Fellow Members

I've been working on a project and come to a situation where I want to create a row in second table (Offers Table) when a new row inserted in first table (Product Variants Table). For that I thought of using laravel created boot event but i think the event is not working properly.

This is my code:

```
 public  static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($variant) {
            $variant->product->categories()->each(function($category){
                $offers = \App\OfferReference::where([['reference_id',$category->id],['reference','Category']])
                ->orWhere([['reference_id',$category->id],['reference','Subcategory']])->get();
                foreach ($offers as $offer) {
                    $table = \App\Offer::where([['product_variant_unique_stock_id',$variant->unique_stock_id],['offer_reference_id',$offer->id]])->first();
                    if(!$table)
                    {
                        $table = new \App\Offer;
                        $table->product_variant_unique_stock_id = $variant->unique_stock_id;
                        $table->offer_reference_id = $offer->id;
                        $table->save();
                    }
                }
            });
            $offers = \App\OfferReference::where([['reference_id',$variant->product->id],['reference','Product']])->get();
            foreach ($offers as $offer) {
                $table = \App\Offer::where([['product_variant_unique_stock_id',$variant->unique_stock_id],['offer_reference_id',$offer->id]])->first();
                if(!$table)
                {
                    $table = new \App\Offer;
                    $table->product_variant_unique_stock_id = $variant->unique_stock_id;
                    $table->offer_reference_id = $offer->id;
                    $table->save();
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
```

Nothing is creating in offers table.

Can anyone please guide me what i am doing wrong or any solution or idea to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i worked it out!

Actually the code was fine its just i was not passing **$variant** in the **categories->each() function**

The working code is

```
public  static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($variant) {
            $variant->product->categories()->each(function($category) use ($variant) {
                $offers = \App\OfferReference::where([['reference_id',$category->id],['reference','Category']])
                ->orWhere([['reference_id',$category->id],['reference','Subcategory']])->get();
                foreach ($offers as $offer) {
                    $table = \App\Offer::where([['product_variant_unique_stock_id',$variant->unique_stock_id],['offer_reference_id',$offer->id]])->first();
                    if(!$table)
                    {
                        $table = new \App\Offer;
                        $table->product_variant_unique_stock_id = $variant->unique_stock_id;
                        $table->offer_reference_id = $offer->id;
                        $table->save();
                    }
                }
            });
            $offers = \App\OfferReference::where([['reference_id',$variant->product->id],['reference','Product']])->get();
            foreach ($offers as $offer) {
                $table = \App\Offer::where([['product_variant_unique_stock_id',$variant->unique_stock_id],['offer_reference_id',$offer->id]])->first();
                if(!$table)
                {
                    $table = new \App\Offer;
                    $table->product_variant_unique_stock_id = $variant->unique_stock_id;
                    $table->offer_reference_id = $offer->id;
                    $table->save();
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
```

the **use ($variant)** on **line 4** is what stopping my code from working